Heat transport in earth's gravitational field
Consider a Carnot machine that exploits the earth's atmospheric temperature gradient using air at lower altitude as a warm reservoir and air at higher altitude as a cold reservoir. Due to the temperature difference it will have a nonzero efficiency and thus performs some work $W$. It will also reduce the heat of the warm reservoir by some $Q_H$ and raise the heat of the cold reservoir by $Q_C$. In order to circumvent an explanation of parts of the machine being moved within the gravitational field, consider the Carnot machine to be small in the earth's radial direction, but to have ways of heat transport to actually make use of a non-negligible temperature difference.
At first glance this looks like a violation of the second law of thermodynamics, but I believe the solution lies within the heat transport between reservoirs and machine. Obviously, if I am using convection or conduction (momentum transfer), then the carrier will need to overcome the gravtational field and thus the required heat would not reach the Carnot machine. If I were to use radiation, however, the only possibility of losing energy from photons moving away from earth would be due to gravitational redshift, but that should be vanishingly small.
Is there an easy way to see why the above machine should not work?

At first glance this looks like a violation of the second law of thermodynamics how so?

Ah sorry, this should happen after running the machine for a while and then turning it off. The air in the earth's athmosphere should equilibrate back into its initial state (say I turn the work of the Carnot machine back into heat so I am not cooling down the atmosphere). This process transports heat from warm to cold and then back to warm, the last bit should be a violation of the second law, no?

No physical law, including the Second Law, prohibits the machine from working.
When evaluating whether the Second Law is possibly being violated, the key aspect to check is whether total entropy is decreasing.
Since substantial entropy is generated via heating by the Sun, let's consider an isolated column of air with an existing temperature gradient. Gravity itself can't maintain a temperature gradient; the temperature over the column will tend to equalize. If you run a heat engine between the top and bottom, you'll speed up this process, and then no more free energy will be available once the temperature is uniform. At no point does the total entropy of the air in the column decrease.
So what causes the lapse rate to form and persist, and reform after you use your hypothetical heat engine? Natural convection driven by the Sun's heating. Ultimately, your machine is solar-driven. And there's no total entropy decrease that one can point to that would correspond to a Second Law violation.

Thanks a lot, I always thought the temperature gradient was a purely gravitational effect, but this makes sense.
